# EM Radiations, wavelength and Wein's Law of Displacement

Tags: electromagnetism

Why can black bodies emit all wavelength radiations?

Also, in Wein's law of displacement, how do we sat that wavelength corresponding to the max intensity of the radiation is inversely proportional to the temperature?